# How to detect if a class is final in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, final, type-traits

Code first.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A final {};
struct B {};

int main()
{ 
    cout << is_final<A>::value << endl; // Output true
    cout << is_final<B>::value << endl; // Output false

    return 0; 
}
```

**How to implement the class is_final?**

Comment: Wild guess: it’s not possible. the C++ type system doesn’t maintain a traversable link to subclasses of a given class, only the other way round (through the inheritance chain). What do you actually want to achieve? (Still +1, interesting, concisely asked question.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to trigger a SFINAE condition that would let you test for this.  I know that G++ implements a __is_final keyword which does it, but that's all I've found.  It's implementation dependent, but could do in a limited case.

Comment: I think it's impossible aswell without compiler support. Might be worth [proposing for a future standard](http://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-future-proposals) to add `std::is_final`.

Comment: I want to use macro to insert tedious code into a class, but the code requires the class must not be inherited. So, I want to add static_assert(is_final<T>::value, "The macro cannot be insertd into a non-final class"); inside macro body.

Comment: Update: `std::final` is in C++14

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type traits are usually implemented using the SFINAE idiom, which places a potentially ill-formed expression inside a function template declaration. Substituting the typename in question into the declaration results in an error, but the error is suppressed in that context, so the declaration is either used or not. But a fallback overload backs up the potentially missing declaration. Another bit of code accesses the function to detect whether the sensitive overload or only the backup was instantiated.

This won't work for `final` because it can only cause failure during template instantiation of a class. There's no way to overload classes, and no way to tentatively define a class that will fail but not halt compilation in case it's derived from final.

Standard quote, C++11 §14.8.2/8:

> Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure. [ Note: The evaluation of the substituted types and expressions can result in side effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and/or function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, etc. Such side effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed. — end note ]

Comment: much later (C++14) `std::is_final` was added, that most probably uses compiler intrinsic

Answer (score 31):

As the implementer of GCC's `__is_final` intrinisic (for [PR 51365](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR51365)) I'm pretty sure it can't be done in a library, it needs compiler support.

You can do some very clever things with C++11's SFINAE for expressions feature but to detect whether a class is final you'd need to derive from it, and instantiate the derived type, in a template argument deduction context, but deriving from a class is done in a declaration not an expression.

Also, you should think about whether you only want to know if the `final` pseudo-keyword was used, or if a class is un-derivable for other reasons, such as having only private constructors.

Comment: If this ever gets considered for the standard, it may need two proposals - `is_final` and `is_derivable`, both implementing different semantics. Although, in TMP, having private constructors doesn't hinder from deriving as you normally never construct such types.

Comment: @Xeo `is_derivable` would be a misnomer for a test of accessible constructors, since you can still derive and use a class with no nonstatic members without a constructor.

Comment: … uh, what I meant to say was that you can use the static members.

Comment: I think the committee would rather vote for `final(classOrMethod)` and `override(classOrMethod)` or similar just to re-use the existing keywords instead of introducing new ones.

Answer (score -4):

Not sure if this is what you want but you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

template<typename T>
struct is_final {
    static const bool value = false;
};
template<>
struct is_final<Bar> {
    static const bool value = true;
};


int main(void) {
    std::cout << is_final<Foo>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_final<Bar>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Well I understand you can't do it without specifying yourself if the class is final or not.

Comment: @gvd `final` is a (new, context-conditional) keyword that can be applied to a class declaration. He wants to detect whether it was used.