# Does 'final' specifier add any overhead?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Does using specifier `final` on a `class` or on a `function` add any memory or cpu overhead, or is it used at compile time only?

And how does `std::is_final` recognise what is final?

Comment: The answer to the second part is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809359/how-to-detect-if-a-class-is-final-in-c11

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It actually can reduce overhead.  And in rare cases, increase it.

If you have a pointer to a `final` class `A`, any virtual method calls can be de-virtualized and called directly.  Similarly, a call to a virtual `final` method can be de-virtualized.  In addition, the inheritance tree of a `final` class is fixed, even if it contains `virtual` parent classes, so you can de-virtualize some parent access.

Each of these de-virtualizations reduce or eliminate the requirement that a run-time structure (the vtable) be queried.

There can be a slight downside.  Some coding techniques rely on vtable access to avoid direct access to a symbol, and then do not export the symbol.  Accessing a vtable can be done via convention (without symbols from a library, just the header file for the classes in question), while accessing a method directly involves linking against that symbol.

This breaks one form of dynamic C++ library linking (where you avoid linking more than a dll loading symbol and/or C linkage functions that return pointers, and classes are exported via their vtables).

It is also possible that if you link against a symbol in a dynamic library, the dynamic library symbol load could be more expensive than the vtable lookup.  I have not experienced or profiled this, but I have seen it claimed.  The benefits should, in general, outweigh such costs.  Any such cost is a quality of implementation issue, as the cost is not mandated to occur because the method is `final`.

Finally, `final` inhibits the empty base optimization trick on classes, where someone knows your class has no state, and inherits from it to reduce the overhead of "storing" an instance of your class from 1 byte to 0 bytes.  If your class is empty and contains no virtual methods/inheritance, don't use `final` to avoid this being blocked.  There is no equivalent for `final` functions.

Other than the EBO optimization issue (which only occurs with empty types), any overhead from `final` comes from how other code interacts with it, and will be rare.  Far more often it will make other code faster, as directly interacting with a method enables both a more direct call of the method, and can lead to knock-on optimizations (because the call can be more fully understood by the compiler).

Marking anything except an empty type as `final` when it is final is almost certainly harmless at run time.  Doing so on classes with virtual functions and inheritance is likely to be beneficial at run time.

---

`std::is_final` and similar traits are almost all implemented via compiler built-in magic.  A good number of the traits in `std` require such magic.  See [How to detect if a class is final in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13809359/1774667) (thanks to @Csq for finding that)

Comment: @TemplateRex EBO pessimization?  You cannot use empty base optimization on a final class, because you cannot inherit from it.  EBO uses inheritance to make empty classes (in certain circumstances) use zero space.  As you cannot inherit from a final class, it doesn't work if you are final.

Comment: I'm thinking that a `template<class T> struct Finalized final : T {};` is a nice utility to get around it. Just inherit from `B` for EBO and typedef `Finalized<B>` for users.

Comment: @templaterex needs constructor inheritance.

Comment: ya, correct, and annoyingly also default constructor by hand. So perhaps not worth the bother.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, it's only used at compile-time
2. Magic  ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809359/how-to-detect-if-a-class-is-final-in-c11) for further info - thanks Csq for link)

Comment: Are you sure that marking a class `final` does not force creation of a vtable for that class, for any compilers?